# Members role command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i been trying to get this command $100ivShiny to give my members the actual rank 100ivShiny. but i cant seem to find the solution.

```
if message.content.startswith('$100ivShiny'):
      role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name="100ivShiny")
      await client.add_role(user, role)
      await client.send_message(channel, "Role added")
```

this is the error i'm getting

```
  File "mod.py", line 29, in on_message
    await client.add_role(user, role)
AttributeError: '<class 'discord.client.Client'>' object has no attribute 'add_role'
```

Comment: well the error tells you exactly what's wrong. `client` does not have an `add_role` method to it. Go read up on Discord's API to find out what the method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coroutine is named [`Client.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.add_roles), not `Client.add_role`.  It would be used like

```
if message.content.startswith('$100ivShiny'):
      role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name="100ivShiny")
      await client.add_roles(user, [role])
      await client.send_message(channel, "Role added")
```

Assuming `message`, `user`, and `channel` are defined appropriately.

If you're writing a lot of commands like this, you should look into using the `discord.ext.commands` extension, it means that you don't have to keep all of your commands in the `on_message` event.